# What race is Big Mom?

Tags: one-piece

Big Mom is massive, but she is not a Giant, so what is she? Is it possible that her family is same as her?

**In Addition:** I think the human show above is not there real parent, maybe Linlin is adopted by them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She is a normal human. In Chapter 866, her parents are shown. They do not share her enormous size.

[image]

Comment: I think the human show below is not there real parent, maybe Linlin is adopted by them

Comment: Wasn't there a mention that lin lin was involved in Dr. Vegapunks experiments?